# Roslyn VSIX Convert local variable to global const

Tags: c#, roslyn, vsix

I'm making a simple Roslyn Extensions to look for potential consts and make them global.  I've written code to convert to a local const first which is working fine:

I have a codeFixProvider who registers a my fix like so:

```
 context.RegisterCodeFix(CodeAction.Create(title: title,
     createChangedDocument: c => this.MakeConstAsync(context.Document, declaration, c),
     equivalenceKey: title),  diagnostic);
```

My Make Const function looks like so:

```
private async Task<Document> MakeConstAsync(Document document, LocalDeclarationStatementSyntax localDeclaration, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    // Remove the leading trivia from the local declaration.
    var firstToken = localDeclaration.GetFirstToken();
    var leadingTrivia = firstToken.LeadingTrivia;
    var trimmedLocal = localDeclaration.ReplaceToken(
        firstToken, firstToken.WithLeadingTrivia(SyntaxTriviaList.Empty));

    localDeclaration.GetNearestParent<ClassDeclarationSyntax>();

    // Create a const token with the leading trivia.
    var constToken = SyntaxFactory.Token(leadingTrivia, SyntaxKind.ConstKeyword, SyntaxFactory.TriviaList(SyntaxFactory.ElasticMarker));

    // Insert the const token into the modifiers list, creating a new modifiers list.
    var newModifiers = trimmedLocal.Modifiers.Insert(0, constToken);

    // If the type of the declaration is 'var', create a new type name
    // for the inferred type.
    var variableDeclaration = localDeclaration.Declaration;
    var variableTypeName = variableDeclaration.Type;
    if (variableTypeName.IsVar)
    {
        var semanticModel = await document.GetSemanticModelAsync(cancellationToken);

        // Special case: Ensure that 'var' isn't actually an alias to another type
        // (e.g. using var = System.String).
        var aliasInfo = semanticModel.GetAliasInfo(variableTypeName);
        if (aliasInfo == null)
        {
            // Retrieve the type inferred for var.
            var type = semanticModel.GetTypeInfo(variableTypeName).ConvertedType;

            // Special case: Ensure that 'var' isn't actually a type named 'var'.
            if (type.Name != "var")
            {
                // Create a new TypeSyntax for the inferred type. Be careful
                // to keep any leading and trailing trivia from the var keyword.
                var typeName = SyntaxFactory.ParseTypeName(type.ToDisplayString())
                    .WithLeadingTrivia(variableTypeName.GetLeadingTrivia())
                    .WithTrailingTrivia(variableTypeName.GetTrailingTrivia());

                // Add an annotation to simplify the type name.
                var simplifiedTypeName = typeName.WithAdditionalAnnotations(Simplifier.Annotation);

                // Replace the type in the variable declaration.
                variableDeclaration = variableDeclaration.WithType(simplifiedTypeName);
            }
        }
    }

    var root = await document.GetSyntaxRootAsync(cancellationToken);

    // Produce the new local declaration.
    var newLocal = trimmedLocal.WithModifiers(newModifiers)
                                .WithDeclaration(variableDeclaration);

    // Add an annotation to format the new local declaration.
    var formattedLocal = newLocal.WithAdditionalAnnotations(Formatter.Annotation);

    // Replace the old local declaration with the new local declaration.
    var newRoot = root.ReplaceNode(localDeclaration, formattedLocal);

    // Return document with transformed tree.
    return document.WithSyntaxRoot(newRoot);
}
```

All of this work fine like so, but when I introduce a function to create a FieldDeclaration, the next time I enter the hive, to check the syntax analysis, I hit Ctrl + . and before anything pop up I get an ambigous One Or More Error occured modal.

```
public FieldDeclarationSyntax ConvertToFieldDeclarationSyntax(SyntaxTokenList modifiers, VariableDeclarationSyntax declaration, SyntaxKind syntaxKind = SyntaxKind.PublicKeyword)
{
    return null;
    //return SyntaxFactory.FieldDeclaration(new SyntaxList<AttributeListSyntax>(), modifiers, declaration);
}
```

I'm not sure why but that function above throws causes an error, I never even reference, for some reason I guess loading that assembly conflicts.  Does anyone know how to make FieldDeclarationSyntax in Roslyn?

**EDIT**

So I turned on all exceptions and now I'm seeing that I get an error

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo' to type 'System.Reflection.ConstructorInfo'.

When Inspecting this now I see additonal error with the stack trace here:

[image]

This occurs when hitting ctrl + . on my highlighted syntax error rule a modal pops up from the hive:[image]

Comment: "It blows up" and "causes an error" don't tell us anything about what the error actually *is*. Please include the precise error details in your question.

Comment: @JonSkeet I would provide more details if there was.  The hive pops up an error modal, with no information on the error

Comment: @JonSkeet I found what's happening now I don't know why, I'm getting a Unable to cast object of type 'System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo' to type 'System.Reflection.ConstructorInfo'.  Could this be caused because my VSIX is a 4.6 application and I'm working against a 4.5 project?

Comment: I don't know - but do you have a stack trace for that exception? You should be able to see where the cast occurs.

Comment: It's coming from mscorlib, I posted a picture with an update.  Just wondering is it proper to use `SyntaxFactory`  I see a lot of code online that references `Syntax` as a static library but I can't find that anywhere?  I have a feeling I'm using mismatched runtimes somewhere

Comment: `SyntaxFactory` is a static class, yes: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/master/src/Compilers/CSharp/Portable/Syntax/SyntaxFactory.cs - I suspect I won't be able to help you, but hopefully someone with more Roslyn experience may be better placed with the extra information.

Comment: @JonSkeet thanks either way your guidance always is a blessing

Comment: (I'm not seeing a picture of a stack trace, btw - just a button. The more information you can include, the better.)

Comment: @JonSkeet sorry I thought I added a photo I'm adding it back in now

Comment: @JonSkeet this is really weird, All of the code works if I inline it in the function.